# F# catch System.Web.Exception

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have written tests with TickSpec (F# version of C# Specflow) to test a web service. When I run the test where I expect the response to come with a 200 OK all is fine. When I intentionally send an incorrect request I receive a 400 Bad Request, but the test fails, although 400 is what I want to get back. So the question is - how do I catch an exception and continue in F#?

This is a snippet of code I have:

```
let sendRequest(requestBody : HttpRequestBody) = 
    let response = Http.Request(url, headers = requestHeaders, body = requestBody)
    let responseStatusCode = response.StatusCode
    let extractedResponseData = 
    // code here to extract data from response
(responseStatusCode, extractedResponseData)
```

The error I am getting is

```
System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

I was hoping that putting a try catch (try with in F#?) around the

```
 let response = Http.Request(url, headers = requestHeaders, body = requestBody)
```

would solve the problem.

Can I do that and how do I do it?

Comment: What specific part are you stuck on?  Have you read the MSDN page here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233194.aspx

Comment: Got it sorted by adding this bit: silentHttpErrors = true to  let response = Http.Request(url, headers = requestHeaders, body = requestBody). That ignores the error and continues.

Comment: @Marta - you are allowed to answer your own questions on SO :)

Comment: @DaveShaw - thanks, will do that.

Answer (score 3):

Adding:

```
   silentHttpErrors = true
```

to:

```
   let response
```

as in:

```
 let response = Http.Request(url, headers = requestHeaders, body = requestBody, silentHttpErrors = true)
```

sorted the problem. Now the tests ignore the System.Net.WebException and I can test the application for behavior related to a 400 bad request.

More here: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html